# Create permanent access token

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to write a script in python to convert group names to their ID. The way I am doing this is via

```
graph.facebook.com/search?q=GROUPNAME&type=group&access_token=XXXXX
```

I can create an access token through the graph API Explorer on developers.facebook.com under tools but this only lasts a couple of hours.

This must be possible as websites such as

```
http://lookup-id.com/
https://www.wallflux.com/facebook_id/
```

offer this service already

How can I make a permenant token? Ive tried looking around but most soloution involve only needing to access a single page/group you own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

Comment: This is not about Page Access Tokens...

Comment: @Tobi Did you read the 5th point in the answer?

Comment: The process my be the same for the access tokens, but this is not a duplicate question IMHO.

Comment: Ive read that learningneverstops and it wasn't the same proccess as listed in his steps.

Comment: If this is not for page access and is via a normal desktop kind of situation then I feel there is another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050362/how-to-get-permanent-access-token-in-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

As the Group Search needs an User Access Token, you'll not be able to get an *eternal* Access Token. The long-lived User Access Tokens are only valid for 60 days and need to be refreshed afterwards.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending